# Unable To Hide Navigation Bar during AlertDialog/LoginDialog

Tags: java, android, uinavigationbar, android-alertdialog, navigationbar

I'm attempting to hide the navigation bar globally through my app running Android 4.2.2

I have managed to use the following (admitadly hackish) method of implementing:

```
getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
```

Which successfully removes the Navigation bar (the fact it is hackish is perfectly fine - this is for a kiosk so it will only be installed on a limited number of devices)

Now I'm attempting to remove the navigation bar in places other than my MainActivity - such as when it reappears during an AlertDialog/LoginDialog.

I'm attempting to use:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(new ContextThemeWrapper(getActivity(),R.style.HoloDarkDialog));
    LayoutInflater inflater = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();

    variables = SingletonVariables.getInstance();

    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login, null);
    EditText userEditText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.loginUserIdEditText);
    getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(8);
```

However this result in the error:

```
The method getWindow() is undefined for the type LoginDialog
```

Does anyone know of a way this might be avoided?

### Edit:  (additional requested source code)

```
// Function to handle show dialog
public void showLogin(View view, String whichActivity) {
    pd = new ProgressDialog(this.getApplicationContext());
    pd.setMessage("Logging in, Please wait....");

    LoginDialog logindialog = new LoginDialog();
    logindialog.setWhichActivity(whichActivity);
    logindialog.show(getFragmentManager(), "MyLogin");
}
```

Comment: `getWindow()` is a method of Activity class. `http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getWindow()
.

Comment: use `getActivity().getWindow()`

Comment: You can use getActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

Answer (score 8):

try this code

```
@Override
public void show() {
    this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);
    super.show();
    int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE_STICKY
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
            | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
    this.getWindow().getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
    this.getWindow().clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE);

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe this can help you?
https://stackoverflow.com/a/23435922/3464293

Smthng like this?

```
View decorView = getActivity().getWindow().getDecorView();
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN;
decorView.setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
```

**Update:**
(source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2844648/3464293)

In your LoginDialog.java add this method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
super.onStart();
Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
window.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE); 
int uiOptions = View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION | View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN; 
window.getDecorView().setSystemUiVisibility(uiOptions);
}
```

and try then. Remove previous updates.

Comment: I tried it... the error went away - however the navigation bar is still shown when the dialog appears

Comment: I tried it. It results in: "The constructor Dialog(LoginDialog) is undefined"

Comment: could you post your code where youre building your login dialog and doing the .show() method? I'm not sure what are you doing now. Dialog(this) takes Context as argument. For example this.getApplicationContext()

Comment: edited answer, try it. You pasted me the class, but where do you instantiate your LoginDialog and use LoginDialog.show()? I'm not sure if my update will run.

Comment: Ok, so you need to try it in the place before you do LoginDialog.show(). Where do you instantiate your LoginDialog? Like LoginDialog dialog = new LoginDialog();?

Comment: public void showLogin(View view, String whichActivity) {

(shown above in a recent edit)

Comment: Using your most recent answer verbatim results in the error: The method getWindow() is undefined for the type LoginDialog


In order to avoid this I simply added getActivity()

here:

 Window dialog_window = logindialog.getActivity().getWindow(); dialog_window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
  logindialog.setWhichActivity(whichActivity);
  
  
  
  however it causes a force close NPE on the line Window dialog_window = logindialog.getActivity().getWindow(); 
  
  
  Any suggestions?

Comment: Ok, for dialogfragment (your LoginDialog extends the Dialogfragment) you need to do a little different thing. I will update my answer in few minutes.

Comment: It works? If yes, then maybe accept the answer, if not then lets try further :)

Comment: I tried your most recent suggestion - the navigation bar still appears when the dialog/edittext appears: http://pastebin.com/RYR5Gwzv

Comment: I've added the requestWindowFeature, try it maybe.