# Setting Android fragment enter and exit transitions?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to set enter and exit transitions for a DialogFragment, which seems straight forward enough. Here is the code from my DrinkDetailActivity that creates the dialog:

```
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //create and display the dialog
            DialogFragment orderFragment = new OrderDrinkDialogFragment();

            //set the slide transition for the fragment
            Transition dialSlide = new Slide();
            dialSlide.setDuration(300);

            orderFragment.setEnterTransition(dialSlide);
            orderFragment.setExitTransition(dialSlide);
            orderFragment.show(getFragmentManager(), "order");
        }
    });
```

And here is the code from my OrderDrinkDialogFragment Class:

```
public class OrderDrinkDialogFragment extends DialogFragment
{
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(DrinkDetailActivity.activity);

        //set up the Linear Layout of the dialog
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(DrinkDetailActivity.activity);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(params);

        //set up the EditText view
        EditText nameField = new EditText(DrinkDetailActivity.activity);
        nameField.setHint(R.string.dialog_name_hint);

        //add the EditText view to the layout
        layout.addView(nameField, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                                                            LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

        //set layout as the view of the dialog
        builder.setView(layout);

        return builder.create();
    }
}
```

`DrinkDetailActivity.activity` is simply `this` from within the instance of `DrinkDetailActivity`. For some reason, the dialog doesn't transition when i `show()` it or when it is dismissed, it simply pops in and out of view. [This](http://www.androiddesignpatterns.com/2014/12/activity-fragment-transitions-in-android-lollipop-part1.html) tutorial helped me a lot in figuring out the Activity transitions for the rest of my app, and I followed the same instructions for fragment transitions as it says. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This worked for me.My slide up animation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="100%"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toXDelta="0" />

</set>
```

and my slide animation is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <translate
        android:duration="@android:integer/config_mediumAnimTime"
        android:fromYDelta="0%p"
        android:interpolator="@android:anim/accelerate_interpolator"
        android:toYDelta="100%p" />

</set>
```

in your styles add this

```
<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/slide_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/slide_down</item>
</style>
```

now finally in your `onCreateDialog()` of Dialog fragment add this

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    final Dialog dialog = super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.DialogAnimation;
    return dialog;
}
```

Comment: If I do that, I get this error: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.Window android.app.Dialog.getWindow()' on a null object reference` , which makes sense because the how would I get the window of the dialog before it is created?

Comment: This works! With a few changes: 1) in slide up animation, change "toXDelta" to "toYDelta", 2) in slide up animation, change "100%" and "0" to "100%p" and "0%p" respectively, and 3) I just did a `Dialog dialog = builder.create();` instead of calling super. Thank you so much for your help! Not sure if I should ask this here, but how would I go about getting the dialog to slide out from under the bottom nav bar?

Comment: try something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23520892/unable-to-hide-navigation-bar-during-alertdialog-logindialog

Comment: That thread is more about hiding the navbar, I want my navbar still there, but i want the dialog to look like it's sliding out from underneath it. I'll look into it more and possibly make a new post if I can't figure it out, thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a style for showing animation on any window like Dialog

```
<style name="AnimDialog" parent="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
    <item name="android:windowAnimationStyle">@style/DialogAnimation</item>
</style>

<style name="DialogAnimation">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/fadein</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/fadeout</item>
</style>
```

For your dialog you need to instantiate like

```
Dialog animatedDialog = new Dialog(MainActivity.this,R.style.AnimDialog);
```

Answer (score -1):

**[DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html) is not just a Dialog but also a Fragment**, see [Basic Dialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html#BasicDialog) for more details on how to use it. You have used onCreateDialog inside a Fragment which might be the cause of your issue. So, use onCreateView to create your fragment dialog view.

Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: Wrong answer, see the Alert Dialog part here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html